# I am trying to use a weather api that I am trying to pull data from i am getting undefined but the property does exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, undefined

I am trying to render some api data but it is giving me an error

```
Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

I am expecting weatherData.weather.description to give me a string like

```
"broken clouds"
```

I know its in there!
When I log weatherData.weather I get

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 803, main: "Clouds", description: "broken clouds", icon: "04n"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Now it is saying it's an array but when I try

```
console.log(weatherData.weather[0].description)
```

I still get the same error above

this is my code

```
import axios from "axios";
import "./weather.css";
function Weather({user}){
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
    const openWeatherApi = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${user.city},us&APPID=${user.apiKey}`;
    useEffect( () => {
        //axios get weather API\\

        axios.get(openWeatherApi)
        .then((response) => {
          setWeatherData(response.data);

        })
      },[])
    return(
        <>
            {console.log(typeof weatherData.weather)} {/* logs object*/ }
            {console.log(weatherData.weather.description)} {/* Cannot read property 'description' of undefined*/ }
            <div className="weather-box">
            <h1 className="weather-city">{weatherData.name}</h1>
            <p className="weather-description"></p>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios call is async function, and template gets rendered immediately while your `weatherData` prop is an empty array. So you are trying to access `description` property from the first element in an empty array, that's why you got an error.

If you place this piece of code into your template, you should be able to see requested data.

```
<h1>{weatherData.length !== 0 ? weatherData.weather[0].description : 'fatching data...'}</h1>
```